# javascript audio record using microphone

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to record audio using microphone and convert it to string format using javascript. Using the below code i am getting the audio and storing it as blob.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then(stream => {
  rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  rec.ondataavailable = e => {
    debugger;
    audioChunks.push(e.data);
    if (rec.state == "inactive") {
      let blob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/x-mpeg-3' });
      debugger;
      audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    }
  }
}).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Now How to get that audio from the audioUrl and convert it to string format?

Note:The audio is being saved in opus format(.ogg)

Comment: Needing a binary file in 'string' format is a little odd. What are you trying to do with that string? If you're trying to upload the file then a Blob would be more appropriate

Comment: I want to send opus audio as input to amazon lex. Please find the below information.                                                                                                         User input in PCM or Opus audio format or text format 

    You can stream audio data to Amazon Lex or you can create a local buffer that captures all of the audio data before sending. In general, you get better performance if you stream audio data rather than buffering the data locally.
Ref Link : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostContent.html

Comment: How to do this?

Comment: You've linked to the documentation... it tells you right there what you need to do, even with examples at the bottom. One thing to be wary of is whether or not this service supports CORS. If not, then you won't be able to do what you require through JS at all.

Comment: It supports CORS. But i want to know how should i convert my opus file to the desired format which lex expects as request in that documentation? Please clarify that.